# Minimal Requirements for Convergence of Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

It is a standard fact that the series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_n}$$
converges if $a_n \gg n^{1+\epsilon}$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Moreover, it will diverge if $a_n \ll n\log(n)^A$ for some number $A$. Now, suppose $a_n \gg n\log(n)^A$ for all $A$. This doesn't necessarily mean that $a_n \gg n^{1+\epsilon}$, but is it known if the series will converge or not?

Any solution or reference would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Fixed typo of $\log(n)^A$ to $n\log(n)^A$

Comment: No, take $a_n = n \log n$.

Comment: Sorry Bongers, I meant to write $n\log(n)^A$ instead of just $\log(n)^A$.

Comment: What is this $\ll$ sign for?

Comment: $\ll$ means that there exists $N,C$ such that $|a_n|\leq Cn\log(n)^A$ for all $n \geq N$.

Comment: Note that if $a_n=n(\log n)^2$ then the series $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{a_n}$ converges.

Comment: @Mastrel Is that notation used by some authors? I have only seen $|a_n| \in \Omega(n \log(n)^A)$.

Comment: It was introduced by Vinogradov and is used frequently in number theory. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_.28Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau.2C_Hardy.2C_and_Vinogradov_notations.29